# Correcting editing-help#code

Tags: bug, status-completed, wording, grammar, help

[Here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code), in the `Preformatted Text` section, the sentence :

> Indent four spaces to create **an** block of preformatted text

Should be

> Indent four spaces to create **a** block of preformatted text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been fixed, according to these Wayback Machine snapshots somewhere late 2021 or early 2022:

- [2021 December 11th](https://web.archive.org/web/20211211064133/https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
- [2022 May 11th](https://web.archive.org/web/20220511014617/https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

[image]